# .htaccess Remove .php keep regular indexing

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I'm using:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
```

This makes it so I don't have to use ".php" at the end of my pages. However, if I don't specify an index it gives a 404.

Example:

example.com/content.php is directed to example.com/content

^ That works perfectly well.

However, if I want to go to a directory like example.com/users it gives a 404 error.
Only example.com/users/index works.

I want to be able to remove .php the way it is doing already, but I still want directories to work without specifying a page(automatically display index.php). I'm not very fluent in regex or htaccess coding so I have been unable to tweek this myself.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with these 2 rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: This seems to be functioning in the same way the old code did. It redirects and removes the .php properly, but directory roots still return a 404 instead of displaying index.php.

Comment: You get 404 for `example.com/users`? Is `/users/` a directory?

Comment: Actually it started working. Thank you!

Just took a sec to update for some reason.

Comment: One more question. Is there a way to make it work on pages with GET as well? So example.com/users/profile.php?userid=76 would turn into example.com/users/profile?userid=76

Again, without the ".php"?

Comment: That's strange, that just barely started working too. Wasn't before and I haven't touched anything. Anyway, thanks again!